# Scala inference on higher kinded types versus evidences

Tags: scala

I am trying to provide some typeclasses implementations which involves higher kinded types, as in the following code:

```
trait Blah[A,B] {
  def apply(b:B):List[A]
}

object Blah {
  implicit def blah1[A,B<:List[A]]:Blah[A,B] = new Blah[A,B]{
    def apply(b:B):List[A] = b
  }

  implicit def blah2[A,B](implicit ev: B<:<List[A]):Blah[A,B] = new Blah[A,B]{
    def apply(b:B):List[A] = b
  }
}

object Stuff {

  def method[A,B](b:B)(implicit blah:Blah[A,B]):List[A] = {
    blah(b)
  }

  method(List(2,3))
}
```

If I remove the method `Blah.blah2` , the compiler fails because it can't resolve an implicit. Why does the second form (using an implicit evidence) works instead, and when it should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Well... its because it is not able to infer correct types as the first `implicit blah1` expects a relation between `A` and `B`.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Blah[A,B] {
  def apply(b:B):List[A]
}

object Blah {
  implicit def blah1[A,B<:List[A]]:Blah[A,B] = new Blah[A,B] {
    def apply(b:B):List[A] = b
  }
}

def method[A,B](b:B)(implicit blah:Blah[A,B]):List[A] = {
  blah(b)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Blah
defined object Blah

method: [A, B](b: B)(implicit blah: Blah[A,B])List[A]

scala> method( List( 4, 5) )
<console>:37: error: could not find implicit value for parameter blah: Blah[A,List[Int]]
              method( List( 4, 5) )
                    ^
```

See... its looking for `implicit` of type `Blah[ A, List[ Int ] ]`

We just need to help it with types and it will work,

```
scala> method[ Int, List[ Int] ]( List( 3, 4, 5 ) )
res1: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```